# Jquery: two animate() in main animate() callback not working. Suggestions?

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I am trying to put two .animate() in my main animate() callback. Not working? Any suggestions? Thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc.

```
 $('#wrapper li').click(function () {

     //Here is set my variables
     $('#wrapper li').slice(startLi, endLi).animate({
         "left": '-=' + leftDistance
     }, "fast", function () {
         $('#wrapper li').slice(indexLi + 1, endLi).stop().animate({
             "left": "+=225px"
         }, "slow", function () {
             $('#wrapper li').slice(indexLi + 1, endLi).stop().animate({
                 "left": "-=225px"
             }, "slow");
         }
         });


     }); // Close of $('#wrapper li').click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code without syntax errors:

```
 $('#wrapper li').click(function () {

     //Here is set my variables
     $('#wrapper li').slice(startLi, endLi).animate({
         "left": '-=' + leftDistance
     }, "fast", function () {
         $('#wrapper li').slice(indexLi + 1, endLi).stop().animate({
             "left": "+=225px"
         }, "slow", function () {
             $('#wrapper li').slice(indexLi + 1, endLi).stop().animate({
                 "left": "-=225px"
             }, "slow");
         });
     });
 });
```

It will at least run now.

Comment: Hello Esailija, thank you very much! The syntax correction corrected the problem. I am new to Jquery and I am little confused with the syntax standards. Any good link to suggest to learn proper syntax?

Comment: @user1162116 the syntax isn't jQuery, it's javascript. jQuery is just a bunch of javascript that your other javascript can use. I guess you could start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax